# Why Javascript codes cannot be executed when async or defer are set in script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, async.js

I used `JavaScript` in `script tag` in `html` like this:

```
<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

With use of above code, `file.js` is linked to our html page. But when we add `async` or `defer` to the `script tag`, `file.js` cannot be executed in these codes:

```
<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" async="async"></script>
<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
```

Could you help me, please?
Why such problem I faced with it?

In addition, for more clarifying I add a section of html comprised of file.js loading as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>

 <title>Dr.Kayvanfar</title>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Main_CSS.css" />
   
 <noscript> Your browswer don't support JS</noscript>

 </head>



 <body>
   <div id="container" style="width:1500px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;color:blue;">
     <div id="header" style="height:100px;background-color:rgb(0,0,0); margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px; color:rgb(255,255,255);padding-top:5%">
       <span class="topheader">Future Students</span>
       <span class="topheader">Current Students</span>
       <span class="topheader">Research & Teaching</span>
       <span class="topheader">Communities</span>
       **<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" async ></script>**
     </div>

     </body>
   
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
// Or
<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
// Or
<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" async defer></script>
```

When to use which one:

- If the script is modular and does not rely on any scripts then use async.
- If script is relied on any other script then use defer.

Though you can use both:

> If you specify both, async takes precedence on modern browsers, while older browsers that support defer but not async will fallback to defer.

[Source](https://medium.com/@gowtham.kosaraju/async-vs-defer-in-html-script-tag-b3eac91aef2a)

Comment: Where is `file.js` located? Are you linking to it correctly?

Comment: It was linked correctly. Because it works without defer and async values. file.js and the html file are located in a same folder in my case.

Comment: That's odd. What exactly isn't working? Is any of the code from file.js running how you want it?

Comment: I write a simple code in file.js as document.write("something").

Comment: "Using document.write() after an HTML document is fully loaded, will delete all existing HTML." Is this what's happening?

Comment: I remember that html section is loaded fully, but just file.js cannot be loaded with existence of defer or async.

Comment: Have tried doing a `console.log()` instead just to make sure?